# default view not appearing for index.html unless NgRoutingUsePushState is set to false. Why?

Tags: routes, dart, angular-dart

Consider a simple `index.html`:

```html
<body>
  <h1>Example</h1>
  <ng-view></ng-view>
...
```

with the following route initialization code:

```dart
void routeInitializer(Router router, RouteViewFactory viewFactory) {
  viewFactory.configure({
    'hello': ngRoute(
        path: '/hello',
        view: 'view/hello.html'),
    'default': ngRoute(
        defaultRoute: true,
        path: '/default',
        view: 'view/default.html')
  });
};
```

No view is shown when `index.html` is visited, **unless** I add

```dart
  ..factory(NgRoutingUsePushState,
      (_) => new NgRoutingUsePushState.value(false))
```

to my `AngularModule()` initialization, in which case the default view is shown (which is what I want). Why is adding this `NgRoutingUsePushState` configuration necessary?

Comment: Pushed route_hierarchical 0.4.17 Please give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a bug with the `onPopState` mode implementation. For example, `onHashChange` doesn't fire the event when the page first loads, so there's this line to handle the initial load:
https://github.com/angular/route.dart/blob/master/lib/client.dart#L652

When this was implemented `onPopState` did fire the event on page load, so same hack wasn't necessary, but this might have changed. Unfortunately, there's no test for this in the current test suite.

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onpopstate

> Browsers tend to handle the popstate event differently on page load. Chrome and Safari always emit a popstate event on page load, but Firefox doesn't.

This requires closer investigation for how this is handled in Dart.

TO BE CONTINUED...

Update:

a fix was submitted for route_hierarchical: https://github.com/angular/route.dart/commit/9796e36fb0c6eee98e6754203ea5cfbb740b3121

Answer (score 1):

Adding NgRoutingUsePushState is not necessary. I've added the snippet below to my main controller as a temporary fix until the bug is addressed. Relevant link: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=18067

```
import 'dart:js';
import 'dart:html';

class MainController {
  MainController(NgRoutingHelper helper) {
    Event popStateEvent = new Event.eventType('PopStateEvent', 'popstate');
    context['window'].dispatchEvent(popStateEvent);
  }
}
```